# Script not evaluating in non-chromium-based browsers

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, firefox, netsuite

Ok, so my company has a downloads page allowing visitors to download information about products or catalogs which can be found here: [Downloads](http://www.finisinc.com/downloads)

The problem is, when you click on the Brandfolder image, a popup is supposed to appear, which works fine on Google Chrome, Opera, & Safari. However in Internet Explorer and Mozilla Firefox I get a console error stating that:

> Brandfolder is not defined

referring to this file:

```
<div class="container-fluid page-downloads" id="downloads-page-container">
    <div class="content-well col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-12" style="float: none;">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12" style="padding: 0; margin-bottom: 65px;">
            <h1 class="downloads-title">BRANDFOLDER</h1>
            <hr />
            <div class="brandfolder-section col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
<!-- ONCLICK ISSUE --><button onclick="Brandfolder.showEmbed({brandfolder_id: 'finisswim'});return false;" title="FINIS, Inc. Logos &amp; Other Brand Assets" style="border: none; background-color: transparent; padding: 0; margin: 0;">
                    <img src="/sca/site-images/Brandfolder-Web-Button.jpg" class="downloads-banner img-responsive catalog-img" alt="Brand Folder">
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
        ...
        ...
        ...
    </div>
</div>
<!-- BRANDFOLDER JS FILE -->
<script type="text/javascript" async="true" src="//d2sdf28wg0skh3.cloudfront.net/bf.min.js"></script>
```

So I made sure that the file is being loaded and that the content matches, which it does. and then I went to the console, logged `window`, and checked if `Brandfolder` populated, and it didn't (but it did in Chrome, Opera, & Safari).

Since it wasn't working, I pulled it down to my localhost, fired it up and it worked fine on all browsers... **wtf**

my localhost is an exact copy of the live site which is hosted through the NetSuite SuiteCommerce Advanced platform (***hate this platform with a passion***) any ideas what could be going wrong, seeing how it works in chromium-based browsers but not in others, and works fine in a development environment?

any input is appreciated! - Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paul with Brandfolder here. For some reason, probably due to NetSuite, the JS snippet for bf.min.js isn't getting loaded in Firefox but it is on other browsers.

Make sure that the following JS code is getting fired on every browser:

```
<script type="text/javascript">(function(){var e=document.createElement("script");e.type="text/javascript";e.async=!0;e.src="//cdn.brandfolder.com/bf.min.js";var t=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];t.parentNode.insertBefore(e,t)})();</script>
```

Comment: this is what was there originally before it stopped working, so I turned it into a hard script tag and nothing got fixed

Comment: I've reverted it back to this script, i'll have to dig into @RwamDev's answer

Comment: I think I figured it out. The last line of the script needs `()` so that it becomes `window.onload = init();`

I'm pushing a fix now for the file at https://cdn.brandfolder.com/bf.min.js but it'll take about 15 minutes to refresh on the CDN.

Comment: you mean like: `t.parentNode.insertBefore(e,t)();` ??

Comment: Oh, no don't do that @Paul, that will make the script fire before `window.onload` is ready. the problem is the brandfolder script waiting specifically for webkit browsers

Comment: Nope - check out http://cdn.brandfolder.com/bf.min.js and the very last bit should be `bf_init();` (if it's not, it's still propagating throughout the CDN. If you call the code exactly like the solution above it should work in all browsers now.

Comment: I'm confused on why that worked, but it seems to be. Just confused on why invoking the function, and returning the output to `window.onload` worked since `window.onload` needs a function to call.

Comment: Nevermind, I see how it works. minified code is a pain in the ass to read but I get it now. Thanks @PaulArterburn!

Comment: Sure thing. Sorry for providing broken code in the first place! I'm still seeing the old JS on http://www.finisinc.com/downloads - are you waiting to publish the fix?

Comment: our cdn takes some time to propagate, I tested all the browsers and they look good

Answer (score 2):

I set breakpoints on the following function:

```
if (document.addEventListener && document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init, !1),
  /WebKit/i.test(navigator.userAgent))
  var _timer = setInterval(function() {
    /loaded|complete/.test(document.readyState) && (init(),
    clearInterval(_timer))
  }
  , 10);
window.onload = init;
```

The init function is called only on webkit because of the `/WebKit/i.test(navigator.userAgent)` statement.

In my opinion the DOMContentLoaded event is fired before the script is loaded successfully.

Comment: I'll see about having the script load in a `window.onload` and see if that helps..

Comment: okay, so this helps a lot actually. However I'm confused on why it works fine in a local instance, any ideas?

Comment: You helped aid @PaulArterburn in correcting the problem!